# Is NLTK's naive Bayes Classifier suitable for commercial applications?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, nltk

I need to train a naive Bayes classifier on two corpuses consisting of approx. 15,000 tokens each. I'm using a basic bag of words feature extractor with binary labeling and I'm wondering if NLTK is powerful enough to handle all this data without significantly slowing down run time if such an application were to gain many users. The program would basically be classifying a regular stream of text messages from potentially thousands of users. Are there other machine learning packages you'd recommend integrating with NLTK if it isn't suitable?

Comment: No experience with the learners in NLTK, but I can always recommend [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.sf.net); I implemented the naive Bayes classes in that lib and optimized the tf-idf vectorizer. Naive Bayes training on such a (small!) corpus shouldn't take more than a few seconds with the scikit and applying the classifier is dirt cheap.

Answer (score 3):

Your corpora are not very big, so NLTK should do the job. However,I wouldn't recommend it in general, it is quite slow and buggy in places. [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) is a more powerful tool, but the fact that it can do so much more makes it harder to understand. If Naive Bayes is all you plan to use, it would probably be fastest to code it yourself.

EDIT (much later):

Try [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/), it is very easy to use.